# How to use javax validation with autovalue builder?

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator, auto-value

How can I validate properties of my autovalue generated java model using javax validation ?

```
@AutoValue
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AutoValue_Animal.Builder.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class Animal {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public abstract String name();

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public abstract int age();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_Animal.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {

        @JsonProperty("name")
        @NotEmpty
        abstract Builder name(String value);

        @JsonProperty("age")
        @Max(10)
        abstract Builder age(int value);

        abstract Animal build();

    }
}
```

In this example, `@Max(10)` and `@NotEmpty` do not work. Why? I use hibernate validator implementation.

Comment: Try annotating the builder with ```@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "")```